# How does Romanoff communicate with Barton in Age of Ultron

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

After Ultron captured Romanov in Age of Ultron, Stark asked Barton to find an off the grid way to communicate with Romanoff.

They used Morse code.

**How was the Morse code signal transmitted between them?** It could not be over the internet or Ultron would hear it.  Is there some technology used for that purpose in MCU?

Answer (score 7):

As a ham radio operator, I can assure you that we do communicate over those distances with very low power using Morse code. There is a "thousand miles per watt" award for low power operators.  Reliably is relative.  If the ionosphere is co-operative, it is possible but not  reliable like a satellite telephone.  Barton had a "Software Defined Receiver", the most sensitive radio ever designed, so the only variable would be the frequency.  If there was an agreed upon frequency in the HF band, it could happen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a scene later on after her capture where Romanoff has taken an old radio (probably a shortwave set) in the room she is locked in and modified it to enable it to broadcast. She used that to broadcast the message using Morse over radio waves.

Comment: It's possible. We also don't exactly what may have happened meanwhile. People are still highly active on radios around the world. HAM radio operators or others might have passed the message on.

Comment: Cold war radio spy communications, still good in this day and age

Comment: Medium and Long Wave AM Radio can be sent all across the world https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_wave. From your doubts I must assume that you cannot be older than 30 years ;)